# Using existing tools with a custom database

Tags: database, entity-framework

I have a large set of data on a local disk. This data is updated daily by a 3rd party program. I know the format of the data files, and I've written code to read them. To make use of this data I found myself writing a lot of database type code. So I started looking into using existing tools such as LINQ, SQL, The Entity Framework, etc.

This is a large amount data and it is updated daily, so I don't want to duplicate it. Is it possible to setup The Entity Framework or similar tools so that they read data in a custom format?

Comment: Can you clarify the question some? Explain what's special about the custom format? You mean that it's a proprietary data type that can't be read by commercial tools? Or that it's not compliant with relational database standards? Why is it you have had to write database type code - can this data not be transitioned into an existing database product?

Comment: I haven't taken a database course in 20 years, so I have little understanding of the concepts and terminology. So I apologize for any confusion. The data is not proprietary, it is just in an old custom binary format. It contains dozens of directorys, header files in each directory with information about the files, and files containing things like dates and floating point numbers. Like I said before, I can read the data.

Comment: What I meant by database type code, is that most of the code I am writing now is for doing things like searching through the directories to find dates in a certain range. Things that would easily be done in a database. The reason I didn't want to transition it to a database product is because the data is updated daily. So if I transition it to a database, that new database will be out of date in a day. And I don't want to maintain two giant databases.

Comment: Also, I do not want to write to the database. I want the 3rd party program to write to the database, and I want to read it.

Comment: So you must update third party program to use database instead of files. There is no answer to your question. EF and Linq-to-SQL works on database. If you want to use them you must have data in database and you must either modify 3rd party program (or request this modification from the vendor) or you must read them and fill them to database and do it every day to have current data. Making EF work with your files would mean to write whole database abstraction on top of them including SQL querying engine and expose it as DB driver to EF.

Comment: I cannot modify the 3rd party program. I wanted to make EF work with my files, or have someone knowledgeable suggest an alternative. I guess you are saying that would be a prohibitive amount of work. And my only reasonable option is to write code to translate my database into SQL. And then run that program daily and maintain two databases.